# Need PHP to analyse SQL command and place rows in correct position

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am using a hybrid of PHP and JQUERY Slider Menu and now I am trying to implement a CMS back-end system for when I leave my company on Paternity leave.

So far I have 5 parts to the code:

- Header, this has "0" as the SubID and URL is NULL
- Sub-Header, this lists the ID from its parent category and URL is not NULL
- Link, this has "0" as the SubID and URL is not NULL but with CSS looks like a header
- Visible, this is either 1 or 0 and dictates if the record is shown or not
- Order, this counts in ascending order the records.

So I need the SQL to read every row of the database (TinyINT so only about 10 records) and decide whether the row is a header, sub-header or a link.

I can get the database to find all headers, then arrange the sub-headers into the correct header, but I have to code the links separately instead of showing it in number order.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php
require("includes/connection.php");
$conHeaderSQL = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE conSubID = '0' AND conURL IS NULL AND conVis = 1 ORDER BY conOrder";
$conHeaderResult = $glob->query($conHeaderSQL) or die(mysqli_error());
if($conHeaderResult){
    while($conHeaderRow = $conHeaderResult->fetch_object()){
        echo "<p class='menuHeader' style='cursor:pointer'>";
        echo $conHeaderRow->conHeader;
        echo "</p>";
        $conSubHeaderSQL = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE conSubID = $conHeaderRow->conID AND conVis = 1 ORDER BY conOrder";
        $conSubHeaderResult = $glob->query($conSubHeaderSQL) or die(mysqli_error());
        if($conSubHeaderResult){
            while($conSubHeaderRow = $conSubHeaderResult->fetch_object()){
                echo "<div class='msg_body'><ul>";
                echo "<li><a href='$conSubHeaderRow->conURL' class='menuText'>{$conSubHeaderRow->conHeader}</a></li>";
                echo "</ul></div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
$conLinkSQL = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE conURL IS NOT NULL AND conBody IS NULL AND conSubID = '0' AND conVis = 1 ORDER BY conOrder";
$conLinkResult = $glob->query($conLinkSQL) or die(mysqli_error());
if($conLinkResult){
    while($conLinkRow = $conLinkResult->fetch_object()){
        echo "<p class='menuHeader'>";
        echo "<a href='$conLinkRow->conURL' class='noDecorations'>$conLinkRow->conHeader</a>";
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me place the headers and links in the same numbered order?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to incorporate the links into the headers would be to use an `UNION` in your SQL.

```
(SELECT ...) -- headers
UNION
(SELECT ...) -- links
ORDER BY conOrder
```

For each line fetched, you'll have to distinguish headers and links, but your code can stay quite similar to what it is now.

When you return from paternity leave, you could try to change your code in depth. Right now, you're sending a new SQL query for each header. So if you have 10 headers you'll send 11 queries to the server (1 for the headers, 10 for subheaders). I suggest you try to replace all your queries by a single one. You'll need to auto-join, probably with a `content as c1 LEFT JOIN content AS c2 ON c2.conSubId=c1.conId`. Maybe you'll take time to achive it, but getting to kown SQL better is truly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the way the 3 sets of data can not be easily distinguished, if you add a new column `linktypeid` to `content`

And a linktype table e.g:

```
1 = menu Header
2 = sub menu
3 = link
```

It would simplify the selection criteria, attach meaning to the content types, and allow you to order by the column, why not.